# cant update data in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
TextView desc,details,responsibility,status,txtdate;
EditText equipment_id;
DBController controller = new DBController(this,null,null,1);
ImageButton btnupdate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_update_equiments);

    equipment_id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtequipmentid);
    desc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdescription);
    details = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdetails);
    status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
    txtdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
    responsibility = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtresponsibilitycenter);
    btnupdate = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnupdate);

    //desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   // responsibility.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   // btnupdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    txtdate.setText(formattedDate);

        //update data
    btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                //String status = "1";
                controller = new DBController(getApplicationContext(), null, null ,1);
                SQLiteDatabase database = controller.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues data = new ContentValues();

                data.put("description", desc.getText().toString());
                data.put("details", details.getText().toString());
                data.put("responsibility_center",responsibility.getText().toString());
                data.put("status", status.getText().toString());
                data.put("date_taken", txtdate.getText().toString());

                database.update("tbl_equipments", data, "equipment_id=" + equipment_id.getText().toString(), null);
                //database.update("tbl_equipments", data, "equipment_id=" + equipment_id.getText().toString(), null);
                Toast.makeText(Search_Equipments.this, "Updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(Search_Equipments.this,ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

//search equipment
public void searchEquipment(View view){
    if (equipment_id.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(Search_Equipments.this,"Please Enter Equipement No.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else  {
        controller = new DBController(this, null, null , 1);
        Equipment equipment = controller.getEquipment(equipment_id.getText().toString());
        if (equipment != null){

            desc.setText(String.valueOf(equipment.get_description()));
            details.setText(String.valueOf(equipment.get_details()));
            responsibility.setText(String.valueOf(equipment.get_responsibility()));

            desc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responsibility.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnupdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
          Toast.makeText(Search_Equipments.this,"Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

can someone help my code. if passed the condition that data successfully updated but when i display the updated data from database data has not updated, can someone help me to fix this. . . . . . because i dont where is my error there. see my update code. thanks :)

Comment: Is this equipment_id name is same as in your table column name??

Comment: post ur table schema too.....

Comment: query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_equipments (equipment_id TEXT,description TEXT,details TEXT, responsibility_center TEXT, status TEXT ,date_taken DATETIME)";

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to commit the transaction.

```
database.setTransactionSuccessful();
database.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Where did you see an open transaction in the OP's code?